# FireBird 3 и 'RDS microsoft termial server'

Tags: windows, сервер, клиент-сервер, firebird

Доброе время суток форумчане,

Вот подошел ко мне вчера админ, и предложил мою БД на FireBird 3 и всех клиентов (их 21) перикинуть на "RDS microsoft termial server". 
Вот хотел узнать, могут ли возникнуть с эти проблемы?
Зашел на сайт Firebird, ну там о поддержке ни чего не нашел.

Сталкивался ли кни-нибудь с этим?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Ну если он предложил тебе не тока перекинуть, а ещё и саппортить - чё ты паришься? Чинить будет он. Раз предложил - значит по идее должен понимать чё может сломаться и как это фиксить.

Comment: Та не, предложил только купить сервер, перекидка и саппорт останется на мне

Comment: Ну мы у себя юзаем remoteapp для публикации быдлопрог, которые не заворачивают в msi. Проблем вроде нет, но и прог не сильно много. Минимум - разверните на виртуалке роль и пусть несколько пользователей в тестовом режиме погоняют.